# phpMyAdmin and mysql not showing the same database

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have setup WAMP which I managed by using a tutorial and everything seems fine... I am logging into mysql as the root user with full privileges granted and I am able to create databases in mysql and view them by using SHOW DATABASES; so far so good !

...However...
[image: you can see different databases, i am using same account localhost@user on both]
When I access phpMyAdmin and go to the databases section, there are no databases which I have created in mysql, even though phpMyAdmin shows the Database server as User:root@localhost which is the same user I am accessing mysql with.

This situation is also the same when reversed, I can create a database as the root user in phpMyAdmin but the database will not show in mysql when I am logged in as root user and use SHOW DATABASES;

i have tried every soution available ONLINE ..
most of them saying about

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = '';

i have done that too ....
but nothing seems to work....
plzzzz help

Comment: You probable need to switch to the correct DB first. Type in `use newdb` or `use cateringdb` and then `show tables`

Comment: @Alexander - you are not getting me ,,
the database 'cateringdb' is in phpmyadmin....
and its not getting reflected in mysql , so how can i use it in mysql when it does not exist for mysql

Comment: In the CMD Shell, were you also logging in as root to MySQL? I'm not sure how WAMP works, but is it possible you've had mysql on that system before installing WAMP?  Lastly, in a web application it generally isn't advisable to connect as the root user anyway, but I also know you're just getting the basic connection accomplished at this point